# PyGitHub Issue get_comments()

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I want to get all comments of all Github`s issues. I've read the guide here: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pygithub/stable/pygithub.pdf

Following the script:

```
from github import Github

g = Github(base_url="https://github.com/api/v3", login_or_token="XXX")
r = g.get_repo("ORG/REPO")
i = r.get_issues(state='open')
c = i.get_comments()

for issue in c:
    print(issue)
```

But I got the following stdout:

> AttributeError: 'PaginatedList' object has no attribute 'get_comments'

I expected to see every comment from each "issue" collected by the `for`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use an attribute that is not included in `PaginatedList`. For more info: [link](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/PaginatedList.py)

To get comments from issues, you need to extract all comments from a single issue, and keep doing that for every issue. This line is not is not achieving that `c = i.get_comments()`. I located this question which has a solution for the behavior you're looking for: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468403/trying-to-access-github-issue-comments-using-pygithub-library)

Also, there's a couple of things I would like to point out in your code:

1. `g = Github(base_url="https://github.com/api/v3", login_or_token="XXX")`
   This GitHub instance is for Github Enterprise with custom domain. Your URL is missing the domain name. The URL should be in this format: `https://github.xxx.com/api/v3`. If you don't have Enterprise account, you could create an instance using either your login/password or a token. [Reference](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).
2. Are you trying to get comments from a specific organization or from all repositories? I ask because `r = g.get_repo("ORG/REPO")` returns requests from an organization. To specify all repositories instead, use `g.get_repo("repositories)`. Also, note that requests are limited to 5000 requests, and you need to use Link Header to specify more. [Reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories)
3. Your current code specifies comments in open issues, and doesn't consider closed issues as well. To return all comments in all issues, include open and closed issues; `i = r.get_issues(state='all')` [Reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/)